# Changing element left, top, width and height constraints at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

For the purpose of a framework that I am creating I need to setup UIView objects frame property but while the AutoLayout is on I can't do it. 
My idea is that I could remove all layout constraints from the UIView object and then creat new ones based on the frame I want it to have.

So this is what I have, but it does not work giving me an error (below).

```
//Remove current constraints
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];


//create x constraint based on new x value
NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view.superview
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:self.x];
// add new x constrain
[self.view.superview addConstraint:xConstraint];

//create y constraint based on new y value
NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view.superview
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:self.y];

[self.view.superview addConstraint:yConstraint];

//create width constraint based on new width value
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:self.width];

[self.view.superview addConstraint:widthConstraint];

//create height constraint based on new height value
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:self.height];

[self.view.superview addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

This is what happens at runtime:

**EDIT**

After changing `[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];` to `[self.view.superview addConstraint:heightConstraint];` elements display but I am getting the following messages in the console

**Error**

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x91475c0 H:|-(1)-[UIButton:0x728ab00](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x72845b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x729dad0 H:|-(25)-[UIImageView:0x7284920](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x72845b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x72924d0 UIButton:0x728ab00.leading == UIImageView:0x7284920.leading>"
)
```

Comment: In response to your edit: As your error suggests, there may be NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints conflicting with the contraints you are creating manually. You will want to set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of self.view to NO to prevent this issue. EDIT: just saw your second edit and this comment is not correct.

Comment: Side note: I believe for the heightConstraint you should set the second attribute to NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are adding a constraint to self.view that references self.view.superview. This will not work and is the reason you are seeing "Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view? That's illegal."

What exactly are you trying to do? There must be another approach to this problem. Potentially you could add the constraints to the superview, but I'm not completely sure of your situation.

Comment: adding the constraints to the superview fixes that bug but does not fix the concept of positioning the view in reference to its super view based on new x,y,width,height data encapsulated as constraints

Comment: How do you want want self.view to be positioned within its superview and what result are you getting now?

Comment: just edited the question. After I add the constraint to the superview the object positions as I expected but with additional information in the console that I am not doing the right thing. I posted the console info in the question.

Comment: Looking at your edit I see your new issues are due do constraints you created for your subviews (the positions of a button and image within a scroll view). Looking at the output I believe your problem is you are setting the horizontal positions of the button and image to different distances from the left edge of the scroll view. Then you are trying to align the leading edges of the button and the image. These instructions conflict with each other. Start by commenting out the leading edge constraint and you should not see the error.

Comment: Thanks I know what too look for